# Why aren't these variables put in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I'm learning about JavaScript, its scoping, namespaces, and global variables (and how not to use them).

I have a full example below illustrating my question.  I build a namespace "named" JavascriptLearning and then add a Customer function to the namespace.  It works as expected, the JavascriptLearning object/namespace is added to the global object, and the Customer function is added to this namespace.

After this, I then create four variables.  **I'm confused on why these four variables *appName*, *test*, *cust1* and *notNewInstance* are not being added to the global scope, as I thought they would be.**

(I discovered that they weren't being added to the global namespace by debugging in Chrome and viewing the "this" object at then end of execution, at the alert call.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var JavascriptLearning = window.JavascriptLearning || {};

        // Pass in the namespace
        (function(nameSpace) {
            // Uppercased because we are using this function as a "class".
            nameSpace.Customer = function Customer(name, company) {
                // Using this, we create a new object and add properties to it.  Puts an object dynamically with a "shape"
                this.name = name;
                this.company = company;

                // Without a return keyword, the return value would be undefined
                return 0;
            }
        })(JavascriptLearning);
        var appName = "Hello";
        var test = function TEST() { return; }

        // Assigning the new keyword is used to return an object as defined in the function.
        var cust1 = new JavascriptLearning.Customer("Matt", "Company");

        // Not using the new keyword simply uses the return value of the function
        var notNewInstance = JavascriptLearning.Customer("Test", "Company");
        this.alert(cust1.name + " " + cust1.company);
    </script>
</head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: werks4me, I get "Matt Company" in Chrome 21.

Comment: @ken The script runs successfully, I was asking why I wasn't seeing some of my variables in the global scope

Comment: I see the variables in the global scope in Chrome debugger...are you sure you're seeing what you think you're seeing?

Comment: @contactmatt but the script wouldn't execute properly if those vars weren't in the global scope; thus you have given us contradictory information. If the script runs successfully, then you can 'see' the vars in the global scope. Only if you could NOT 'see' them would you get an error, and by your own admission, you do not get an error. Thus, no bug....user error.

Comment: If someone upvotes me to counter the downvote I'll give them a warm cookie.

Answer (score 1):

When a global variable is set in JavaScript, it is automatically added to the window object. Chrome is most likely referencing "this" as the window object.

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have proper namespaces.  When the term `namespace` is used with JavaScript is being used incorrectly to likely refer to a scope assigned to a variable reference.  At this time JavaScript only has function scope, though in the near future it will also have block scope.

You can avoid polluting the global scope by having a single global variable assigned to either an object literal or a function.  Everything immediately inside the object literal would be a property, where anything inside a function needs to be scoped using the var keyword.  In your top level function use the `"use strict";` pragma to check for undeclared references, that would otherwise become implied (accidental) globals.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing those vars in the global namespace. You may be mistaken?

I can contribute something useful for your studies, when declaring vars, you should declare them at the top of the current function. This happens automatically at interpretation time and is called [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

This is demonstrable for example, when you add an alert in the closure you declare,

```
(function(nameSpace) {
  nameSpace.Customer = function Customer(name, company) {
    this.name = name;
    this.company = company;
    alert(appName);

    return 0;
  }
})(JavascriptLearning);
```

Reading the code procedurally, you would expect that to be undefined, but what's happening is this,

```
var JavascriptLearning = window.JavascriptLearning || {};
var var appName, test, cust1, notNewInstance;
```

Then the closure gains a reference to all the vars for the remainder of the function lifetime.